# I'm getting errors from trying to upload images from 2 different fields, server or module issue?

Tags: users, files

Using Drupal 7 and Siteground hosting, when I try to upload images at registration I get this error, but randomly.

> An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (128 MB) that this server supports.

The form has 2 image fields, a multiple upload and the standard user image field. Sometimes it works, sometimes doesn't work with both fields.

What could be wrong, hosting issue or module issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer:

I had the field set to unlimited images, so it got stuck in a loop, better to set a limit, and then set individual images sizes so they don't exceed the limit.

For example:

1. Field image size limit 10 megs
2. Max images upload 12

So with a limit of 128, 12 images of 10 megs = 120 megs = ok

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this is hosting issues. Review drupal and php error log to pin point exactly where the issue happens.

Sometimes the upload is successful to the temp folder but it can't move it to the files directory due to permissions ect..

Comment: Host is Siteground, they can't seem to be able to figure it out...so asking over here...the site was working fine with Namecheap last month

Comment: The only way it could not be a hosting problem is if there's something wrong with the image files themselves. It's very unlikely. Upload some of the problem images to another Drupal install somewhere else, and if you don't have the same problem, you know for sure it's a problem with the hosting platform